# Given that $\int_0^\infty e^{-at}f(t)dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$, what is $\int_0^{\infty}f(t)dt?$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

It is given that $$t>0$$ $$f(0)=1$$ $$f'(0)=0$$ and $$tf''(t)+f'(t)+tf(t)=0$$

From this is can be deduced that $\int_0^\infty e^{-at}f(t)dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$

We then have to find the integral in question.

I really am not sure where to start? Is there something simple I am not seeing?

Comment: What does the title have to do with the post itself? So you are given everything in the post and the integral in the title?

Comment: Using the content given in the post, applying Laplace transforms will give the integral in the title.

Comment: Substitute $a=0$.

Comment: We can substitute $a=0$ if $f \in L^1$.  Do the hypotheses imply that?